# Get all data from DIV JQUERY

Tags: jquery

I try to get all data from a DIV tag. Or I need only text from a div, but the problem is that it has a strong html tag in div. My div block.

```js
var myVar;
myVar = $('.myclass').text();

alert(myVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">100 -
  <strong>265</strong>
</div>
```

and

```
 alert(myVar.value);
```

and

```
 myVar = $('.myclass').html();
```

By first i get nothing, if I try to get value of myVar, I get message "undefined". If i try to get html, i get nothing i my alert.
The easy way I think are to get all data from div and replace strong html tag with nothing.

Comment: Please edit your question and click the `<>` button or press Ctrl+M to open the on site snippet editor, and make a [mcve] of your issue.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/rvkyuaxb/  works fine.

Comment: You can see from the snippet I edited in to your question that your first example works fine. Check the console for errors, and also ensure that you've placed your jQuery logic in a document.ready handler.

Comment: Are you executing your jQuery before the elements it selects have been rendered to the page? Is your jQuery at the end of the document or in a document.ready() handler?

Answer (score 0):

**End Result is without strong tag**

```js
var myVar;
myVar = $('.myclass').text();
$('.result').text(myVar);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="myclass">100 -
  <strong>265</strong>
</div>

<div class="result">

</div>
```